# Retrieving 5 day weather poster from openweathermap API Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

i am getting a 404 error. I just want to retrieve 5 day weather info using openwheathermap api (strictly javascript, no jquery. i am practicing api and javascript and same structure worked with a movie api. what is the mistake i am making. below is my code so far

ps: zoom out to 25% when previewing

```js
function enterkey(){
 
 var enterk = event.which || event.keyCode;
 
 if(enterk==13){
  
  showheather();
 }
 
}

function showheather(){
 
 
 
 var cName = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
 var wgoes = document.getElementById("posterdiv");
 var urlapi = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cName+"";
 
 
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
 http.open("GET",urlapi,true)
 http.send()
 
 
  http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        
        if(http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
            
            var wdata =JSON.parse(http.responseText)
   
   
   
   wgoes.innerHTML = wdata.city.name
   
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  
  
 }
 
 
}
```

```css
#wraper{
margin: 0 auto;
height: 4000px;
width:3840px;

}
#posterdiv{
margin-top: 0%;
height: 2345px;
width:3840px;
border: 5px solid blue;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#searchbox{
height: 300px;
width:3840px;
font-size: 250px;
letter-spacing: 50px;
border-style: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/weather.css">
 
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="wraper">
 
 
 <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Type City Name Here.." onkeydown="enterkey()" >
 
 <div id="posterdiv"></div>
 
 
 
 
 
 
</div> 
 
 
 
 
 
<script src = "../JavaScript/weather.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `urlapi` needs to begin with `http://` or `https://` or even `//` - as it is, your code is trying to read from the host that hosts your page

Comment: i tried http http // before none worked

Comment: it needs to be `http://` not `http //`

Comment: when you tried `http://` what information did you get in the developer tools console and network tabs that may help us determine what you are doing wrong

Comment: are you running this on chrum or IE or edge? because you code **wont** run outside of these inferior browsers with their non-standard global `event` object that you are referring to

Comment: i am using bracket run the html. after putting http:// . GET 404 unauthorized. were you able to run it though  successfully ?

Comment: i meant 401 not 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function enterkey(){
 
 var enterk = event.which || event.keyCode;
 
 if(enterk==13){
  
  showheather();
 }
 
}

function showheather(){
 
 
 
 var cName = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
 var wgoes = document.getElementById("posterdiv");
 var urlapi = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cName+"&appid='enter your app id'";
 
 
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
 http.open("GET",urlapi,true)
 http.send()
 
 
  http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        
        if(http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
            
            var wdata =JSON.parse(http.responseText)
   
   
   
   wgoes.innerHTML = wdata.city.name
   
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  
  
 }
 
 
}
```

api key was the problem. openweathermap require user to have api key. not just the json link. also add http .works like a charm now

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a complete absolute path through `urlapi`

Right now it's a relative path, so you're sending the API call to your own host.

opeanweathermap also requires an API key, which you need to pass in the url.

Comment: pass in your app's key in the url as well.